# pdf_combine() file not searchable

Tags: r, pdf-generation, searchable, pdftools

`pdf_combine()` is a very useful function in pdftools package to combine separate pdf's to one document.

How ever, it seems that combined pdf is NOT searchable with Acrobat Reader, even if separate pdf files as them selves are searchable. Search either does not find anything or points out totally false words.

Did I miss something or is this a fundamental restriction?